# I am new to COBOL and I was messing around with PERFORMS and one of them does not do as intended. Why?

Tags: cobol

This is what the code looks like:

```
  ******************************************************************
  * Author: 
  * Date: 7/26/2022
  * Purpose: Learning
  * Tectonics: cobc
  ******************************************************************
   IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
   PROGRAM-ID. LEARNING-COBOL.
   AUTHOR. Olivier.
   DATE-WRITTEN. July 26th 2022.
   
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   CONFIGURATION SECTION. 

   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.

   01 Turn PIC 9 VALUE 1.
       88 1turn VALUE 1.
       88 4turn VALUE 4.
   01 GameState PIC 9.
       88 GameOver Value 1.
   01 GameMove PIC 9.

   LINKAGE SECTION.              
   
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   
       PERFORM UNTIL GameOver            
       IF 1TURN THEN

       DISPLAY "1 To Play" 

       ELSE IF 4turn THEN

       DISPLAY "4 To Play"
       
       END-IF

       ACCEPT GameMove
       MOVE 4 TO Turn 
       MOVE 1 TO GameState

       END-PERFORM

       
       STOP RUN.
   END PROGRAM LEARNING-COBOL.
```

I do have so coding experience in other languages and I really feel like this should work, but I have absolutely no clue why. I have also tried removing the IF 4turn THEN and only leaving the ELSE and it does work. But why? I think i should exit the loop after waiting for an input, but it just is an infinite loop and doesnt wait for the input (ACCEPT).

Comment: You have not told us what happened and what you expected ???. Cobol's `Perfrom UNTIL` is a **while** loop so you should provide an initial value for **GameState  / GameOver** variable before the loop

Comment: I edited my original post thanks to Bruce Martins post.

Answer (score 3):

You have two `IF` statements, but only one `END-IF`. Add a second `END-IF` immediately following the current `END-IF`.

That will terminate the the two `IF` statements so that the code following the  `END-IF`s will execute.

As @Bruce Martin mentioned in a comment, `GameState` should be given a value, such as, `VALUE 0`. Without the `VALUE` clause the condition `GameOver` could be `true` or `false` depending on the default value provided by the compiler.

Comment: So an ELSE IF in cobol is an IF inside and ELSE so i would have to add a second END-IF?

Comment: @OliveProgrammer - Yes, in modern COBOL, each conditional statement should be terminated with a scope terminator. There are a few cases where that may not be necessary, but it is good practice is to use scope terminators when nesting code, such as, with the nested `IF` statement (`IF` within the `ELSE` branch).

Comment: @OliveProgrammer you could also look at the `evaluate true` option

Comment: There is no ELSE IF statement in COBOL.  There is an IF/ELSE/END-IF or IF/END-IF which can be put inside of another IF clause.  That is why you needed another END-IF.  Personally, when dealing with multiple conditions I use the EVALUATE statement instead, usually EVALUATE TRUE followed by several WHEN conditions and finally END-EVALUATE.